# Using parse_url and editting urls

Tags: php

I know it's easy question and my lack of knowledge, but couldn't figure this out.

Urls are like https://example.com/newcar

Expected output is like:

https://example.com/bmw/newcar

So I tried to write a parse() for that.

```
function parse($urls){
        foreach($urls as $k => $val){
            $scheme = parse_url($val["scheme"]);
            $host = parse_url($val["host"]);
            $path = parse_url($val["path"]);

            $urls = $scheme . $host . "/" . "bmw" . $path;
        }

        return $urls;

    }
```

But clearly parse() is not running properly. 
it's giving `Illegal string offset 'scheme'` error.

Comment: What does `$urls` (input) contain? Also, you're overwriting `$urls` on each iteration. You also need to define what _"is not running properly"_ means. Error messages? Invalid results? Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry, I added the error in the question. $urls is contain an array, and elements are like in the question. @MagnusEriksson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case there are various problems with the function, here's an updated version:

```
function parse($urls) {
    // prepare the result
    $result = [];

    foreach($urls as $url){
        // pass the whole url to parse_url
        $parts = parse_url($url);

        // then reference the parts from that result
        // and add the final version to the to-be-returned-result
        $result[] = $parts['scheme'] . '://' . $parts['host'] . '/bmw' . $parts['path'];
    }

    return $result;
}

print_r(parse([
    'https://example.com/newcar'
]));
```

https://3v4l.org/X9Q2H

Comment: thank you, it's running smoothly and also thank you for explanation as well! ありがとうございます